# Trying to create a messure in PowerBI which give me last 6 month accuracy based on single selected value from date slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

While executing the below DAX expression, I am getting an error "USERELATIONSHIP function can only use the two columns reference participation in relationship".
So could you please help me with that what's wrong with the expression?

```
Accuracy_Last_6_Month = 
VAR ReferenceDate = MAX(Calender[Date])
VAR Last_6Month =
    DATESINPERIOD(
        Calendar_Last6Month[Date].[Date],
        ReferenceDate,
        -6,
        MONTH
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE(
        [Accuracy],
        REMOVEFILTERS(Calender[Date]),
        KEEPFILTERS(Last_6Month),
        USERELATIONSHIP(Calender[Date],Calendar_Last6Month[Date].[Date])
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Relationship created between tables as inactivated form:

[image: Relationship created between tables as inactivated form]

Columns used in both the table:

[image: Columns used in both the table]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a single Calendar. Your second calendar is redundant.

I would write something like this:

```
Accuracy_Last_6_Month = 

CALCULATE([Accuracy], 
FILTER(ALL(Calender), 
Calender[Date] > MAX(Calender[Date])-180 && 
Calender[Date] <= MAX(Calender[Date])))
```

Comment: Sometimes a second calendar is useful. It looks like the OP is doing something similar to what [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/show-previous-6-months-of-data-from-single-slicer-selection/) describes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error is because you are using `Calendar_Last6Month[Date].[Date]` inside USERELATIONSHIP, which isn't actually a table column. Try deleting that `.[Date]` suffix everywhere in your measure:

```
Accuracy_Last_6_Month =
VAR ReferenceDate = MAX ( Calender[Date] )
VAR Last_6Month =
    DATESINPERIOD ( Calendar_Last6Month[Date], ReferenceDate, -6, MONTH )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        [Accuracy],
        REMOVEFILTERS ( Calender[Date] ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( Last_6Month ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( Calender[Date], Calendar_Last6Month[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

I generally avoid using [these Time Intelligence suffixes](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/when-to-use-Date-date/m-p/500274) entirely.